# What do the abbreviations in OOM Killer memory statistics report mean?

Tags: linux, out-of-memory

When OOM Killer or kernel reports memory state, it uses the next abbreviations

```
Node 0 DMA: 26*4kB (M) 53*8kB (UM) 33*16kB (ME) 23*32kB (UME) 6*64kB (ME) 7*128kB (UME) 1*256kB (M) 2*512kB (ME) 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 4352kB
Node 0 DMA32: 803*4kB (UME) 3701*8kB (UMEH) 830*16kB (UMH) 2*32kB (H) 0*64kB 0*128kB 1*256kB (H) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 46420kB
```

I understand some of them, for example `M` - movable `UMH` - unmovable high. But I can not find what means `E` 
Where I can find documentation about it?

My case, I have the next message

```
page allocation stalls for 27840ms, order:0, mode:0x14200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE)
```

what means process requests 4kb page `(2^0 * 4kb)`, that should be coded as (MH) Am I right? Or `HIGHUSER` is coded in different way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are migration types, defined in [`mm/page_alloc.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.12/source/mm/page_alloc.c#L4999) in the kernel:

```
        static const char types[MIGRATE_TYPES] = {
                [MIGRATE_UNMOVABLE]     = 'U',
                [MIGRATE_MOVABLE]       = 'M',
                [MIGRATE_RECLAIMABLE]   = 'E',
                [MIGRATE_HIGHATOMIC]    = 'H',
#ifdef CONFIG_CMA
                [MIGRATE_CMA]           = 'C',
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_MEMORY_ISOLATION
                [MIGRATE_ISOLATE]       = 'I',
#endif
        };
```

The types themselves are defined in [`include/linux/mmzone.h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.12/source/include/linux/mmzone.h#L39).

So `E` means reclaimable, and `H` means “high atomic”, *i.e.* “high-order atomic allocation”.